# How can i auto logon to different servers on MIRC automatically, join certain channels and have a diff nick for each server?

Tags: irc, mirc

How can i auto logon to different servers on MIRC automatically, join certain channels and have a diff nick for each server?

Comment: i'm using the mirc client ;)

Answer (score 11):

**auto connect multi-server**: `Menu "Tools" > "Script Editor" > Tab "Remote"` add somthing like this:

```
on *:START:{
  server irc.network1.com
  server -m irc.network2.org
  server -m irc.network3.net
}
```

**change your nick by network**: `Menu "Tools" > "Options..." > Category "Connect\Options" > Button "Perform..." > Check "Enable perform on connect" > Choose (or Add) your Network > Add the following to the text box:`

```
/nick yournick
```

**join a channel** (still in the same box):

```
/join #yourchannel
```

and as stated by Idigas, you could add any mirc commands there

(There's an alternative to auto join a channel: `Join your channel > Menu "(Tools >) Favorites" > "Add to Favorites..." > Check "Join on connect" > OK`)

**update**: you can also do everything, adapting the auto-connect script: `server [-m] irc.network.org -i yournick alternativenick -jn #yourchannel1,#yourchannel2`

and to connect to any server of a network group, simply replace the server by the group name: e.g. replace "irc.freenode.net" by "freenode"

("/help /server" to get all the /server switch)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what irc client you are using, I highly recommend Hix Script. You can download it at rupertonline.ca/hix/main.htm within this client you can set it to auto login to multiple servers and multiple channels within the server. The commands are /join #channel and /join serv.serverinfo.com for example.

Comment: it sounds like the OP may be using the MIRC (aka mIRC) client (http://www.mirc.com/) ... ya know, since he mentioned it in the title, and the question, and the tags...

Comment: Hix script is mIRC its just its own mod for it.

Comment: You don't need extra scripts for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

For some (unknown to me) reason I don't have mirc on the machine I'm writing this from, so I'll just write it out as I remember, and you try to find it through the interface.
Mirc remembers networks rather then servers ... you can have a lot of servers for a certain network (for example, FreeNode). Somewhere in there there is an option called "Perform" ... in it you script what you want mirc to do upon connecting to a certain network/server ... for example,

```
/nick nixnub
/msg nickserv ghost nixnub nixnubs_password
/nick nixnub2
/msg nickserv identify nixnubs_password
/join #myfavouritechannel
```

will identify you to nickserv, and take over your usual nick if you have it registered. Commands in it are standard mirc commands (standard IRC commands in most cases) ... you can configure this for every network individually.

Btw, when copying mirc to another machine copy file perform.ini from its directory - it is where these mini scripts are saved.

Comment: I don't understand the order of yours commands, the "/msg nickserv ghost..." shouldn't be first? And why have two "/nick" if you are identified on nickserv?

Comment: @fluxtendu - Good grief. I don't even remember answering this any more :) ... anyways, to oyur question: because if someone on that server is already under "nixnub" you won't be able to take it from him in the first go. So use a temp one.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following script which will look in your channel favourites for all autojoin channels and make sure that mIRC is connected to the network associated with that channel.

```
on *:start: AutoConnect

alias AutoConnect {
  ; Ensure we are connected to all existing servers
  var %n = $null
  var %i = $scon(0)
  while (%i) {
    %n = $addtok(%n,$scon(%i).network,32)
    if ($scon(%i).server == $null) scid -t10 $scon(%i) server $scon(%i).network
    dec %i
  }

  ; Now loop through favourites and make sure we are connected
  ; to the networks for all favourite channels that are autojoin.
  var %i = $ini(mirc.ini,chanfolder,0)
  while (%i) {
    var %ini = $readini(mirc.ini,chanfolder,$ini(mirc.ini,chanfolder,%i))
    var %ini = $replace(%ini,$+($chr(44),$chr(44)),$+($chr(44),Z,$chr(44)))
    var %ini = $replace(%ini,$+($chr(44),$chr(44)),$+($chr(44),Z,$chr(44)))
    var %chan = $gettok(%ini,1,44)
    var %net = $noqt($gettok(%ini,4,44))
    var %autojoin = $gettok(%ini,5,44)
    if ((%net != $null) && (!$istok(%n,%net,32)) && (%autojoin)) {
      server -m %net
      %n = $addtok(%n,%net,32)
    }
    dec %i
  }
}
```