# What is the commnad line for mirc to connect and join a channel?

Tags: command-line, irc, mirc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i auto logon to different servers on MIRC automatically, join certain channels and have a diff nick for each server?](https://superuser.com/questions/68904/how-can-i-auto-logon-to-different-servers-on-mirc-automatically-join-certain-cha)

I found that I can launch irc using command line with arguments.

The problem is that it won't join the specific channel.

This is that lunch line:

```
C:\Program Files\mIRC\mirc.exe /join #channel1
```

This command line only connects to the server, but it won't join the specific channel.

How can I connect and join a channel?

Comment: duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/68904/how-can-i-auto-logon-to-different-servers-on-mirc-automatically-join-certain-cha

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting `/join #channel1` in your perform section in the options? Works better for me.

Comment: yes I tried it and it didn't work

Comment: You will have to check the checkbox for "Perform on connect"